# EVENTDATA() function is giving only null values in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, trigger, functions

I'm trying to capture logins time with a trigger using `EVENTDATA()` function.
But It's giving Null values only for all types of events. Can anyone please help me on this?
This is my Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgBlockIP
    ON ALL SERVER
    FOR LOGON
    AS
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @clientip NVARCHAR(15);
       SET @clientip = (
                          SELECT
                             EVENTDATA().value(
                                                 '(/EVENT_INSTANCE/Clienthost)[1]',
                                                 'NVARCHAR(15)'
                                              )
                       );
       IF EXISTS (
                    SELECT ip
                    FROM   master.dbo.BLockedIPAddresses
                    WHERE  ip = @clientip
                 )
       BEGIN
          PRINT 'Your IP Address is blocked';
          ROLLBACK;
       END;
       ELSE
       BEGIN
          DECLARE @Range VARCHAR(15);
          SELECT
             @Range = SUBSTRING(
                                  @clientip,
                                  1,
                                  LEN(@clientip)
                                  - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@clientip))
                               ) + '.*';
          IF EXISTS (
                       SELECT ip
                       FROM   master.dbo.BLockedIPAddresses
                       WHERE  ip = @Range
                    )
          BEGIN
             PRINT 'Your IP Address Range is blocked';
             ROLLBACK;
          END;
       END;
    END;
    GO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XML is case sensitive, and you're not capitalizing things properly.

"Clienthost" should be "ClientHost", which you can see in the [documented schema](https://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/11/eventdata/events.xsd): `<xs:element name="ClientHost" type="SSWNAMEType"/>`

Additionally, the element type SSWNAMEType has a maximum length of 128 bytes, not 15 bytes.

```
<!--  SSWNAMEType  -->
<xs:simpleType name="SSWNAMEType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:maxLength value="128"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```